# Perspective & Affine image warping

Tags: python, image, numpy, opencv, computer-vision

Say I have 2 transformations:

- 2D-Affine Transformation (2x3 size)
- Perspective Transformation(3x3 size)

The purpose of each transformation is to warp ImgA1 to ImgA2

[This picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWXKV.jpg) shows the values of each transformation which clearly shows that they are different.

then I'm using

```
Affineimg_warped=cv2.warpAffine(imgA1,BestMAffine,(imgA2.shape[1], imgA2.shape[0]),imgA2,borderMode=cv2.BORDER_TRANSPARENT)

Projimg_warped=cv2.warpPerspective(imgA1,BestMProj,(imgA2.shape[1], imgA2.shape[0]),imgA2,borderMode=cv2.BORDER_TRANSPARENT)


# plot the results
plt.figure()
plt.title("Affine Transformation")
plt.imshow(Affineimg_warped,cmap='gray')

plt.figure()
plt.title("Projective Transformation")
plt.imshow(Projimg_warped)
```

to warp imgA1 into imgA2 with the two transformations described above.

The problem is that I'm getting the same output (for each pixel x,y Affine_img_warped[x,y]==Projimg_warped[x,y])

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Er0OF.jpg) you can visualize the output and how identical they are.

What I'm missing here?

Comment: You're write both to the same array `imgA2` (the fourth parameter), and then capturing a reference to it in two variable names that you then compare together. i.e. you're comparing the result of `cv2.warpPerspective` with itself, and the result of `cv2.warpAffine` has already been overwritten.

Comment: So you mean that i should delete the argument imgA2 from the warping calls?

Comment: Yes. The destination argument is intended for situations where you want to reuse the same array (avoiding costly allocations).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to chain the warps, it is much simpler (and computationally cheaper)  use one single transform equal to the product of the warps. In this case, as you have an affine warp parametrized by a 2x3 matrix, you'll just extend it to 3x3
adding a row of [0, 0, 1]:

```
BestMAffine3x3 = np.vstack((BestMAffine, np.array([0, 0, 1]))
ChainedWarp = BestMProj.dot(BestMAffine3x3)
ProjImage_warped = cv2.warpPerspective(imgA1, ChainedWarp)
```